# ¿Como asignar checked en JSP?

Tags: java, jsp

tengo un código en JSP el cual tiene un checkbox que si le damos click, filtra cierta informacion.

```
<tr>
    <td class="tituloColumnaIzquierda" width="30%">Solo agencias Activas: </td>
    <td width="70%" class=textoCelda><%= HTMLComponents.getCheckBox("agencias_activas", "","true", request.getParameter("agencias_activas") !=null,false,"document.reporteParamts.submit();", false) %></td>
</tr>
```

Este es el código que tengo que modificar para que, se ingrese a esta seccion, ya se encuentre tildado el checkbox y filtrado los datos.

Muchas gracias!

Comment: y cual es el problema, la verdad no entendi cual es la pregunta o duda que tienes.

Comment: Necesito realizar el proceso a la inversa, en vez de hacer click en el checkbox para filtrar. Quiero que ya esté filtrado y que al hacer click en el checkbox, saque el filtro.

Comment: y que has intentado para lograr ese objetivo?